# Sybase IQ cache database result

Tags: php, caching, sap-iq

I'm using a query that calculates some values on a table with about 11 millions rows. And I need to display the results in real time (on my site), but this calculations need about 1min to execute. The table content changes each 30 mins, so I don't have to recalc the results at each time user reloads the page. How can I cache the results of calculations? Via php (I use odbc) or using some sql statement, some sybase IQ option. Thanks.

*I also asked this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. So sorry for duplicating, can't figure out where is the better place.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. Not optimized, but helpful for me. I insert my calculations into temp table, and add there a column with current date. On a script start I'm checking if table is older then 30mins, and if so, I drop it and crwate again.